# How to match milliseconds dates with different timezones in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I have a database that saves the dates in milliseconds format like *418712400000*. In this question the problem is using this date to save the birthday (*I only can change the back-end application, you cannot answer this question with database structure modification or front-end logic change*). The birthday in the database is: **418705200000** and the birthday that comes from the front-end application is **418712400000**. Using MySQL I convert this timestamps to dates and I get this:

- database birthday: **418705200000** -> `08-04-1983` (dd-mm-yyyy)
- front-end birthday: **418712400000** -> `09-04-1983` (dd-mm-yyyy)

The birthday of the user is `09-04-1983`.

This application is running in Argentina, but the headquarters are in another country (Colombia), people in Argentina don't realize of this mistake.

I know the timezone is affecting this results, how can I convert the dates to match results?

This is the MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    DATE_FORMAT(        FROM_UNIXTIME(birthday / 1000),     '%d-%m-%Y'  ) AS birthday_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(        FROM_UNIXTIME(418712400000 / 1000),     '%d-%m-%Y'  ) AS front_end_date
FROM
    users
WHERE
    userIdentificacion = 30125278
HAVING
    birthday_date = front_end_date
```

Comment: Does the DB have access to the user's timezone?

Comment: Your data is wrong; they are both 09-APRIL-1983, but they are two hours apart.

Comment: Most databases don't store timezone information, rather they store points in time, usually as seconds/milliseconds since the epoch, in GMT.  It is up the application to adjust times coming from the database for the actual end user timezone.  So, I don't think you should be fixing this in the database.

Comment: I believe the solution is convert both timestamps to "neutral" timezone for example (I really don't  know) GMT-0 , you can realize with https://currentmillis.com/ that `birthday` has -3 and the `front_end_date` has -5, maybe that helps? ...

Comment: Yes, you may have to scrub your data and get everything into GMT format.