# How to convert all datetimes to +00:00 depending on their timezones in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timezone, convert-tz

I have a bunch of **datetime** rows in MySQL like:

Birthday

```
422859600000
418705200000
8132400000
869886000000
422859600000
```

If I convert this datetimes to the format **yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0000** I get this:

```
1983-05-27 00:00:00.0000
1983-04-08 22:00:00.0000 (how to convert this to 00:00:00.000)
1970-04-04 04:00:00.0000 (...)
1997-07-25 21:00:00.0000 (...)
1983-05-27 00:00:00.0000
```

Then I do an attempt to convert the timezones with this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME( birthday / 1000 ), '-02:00', '+00:00') as datetime  FROM users
```

And finally I get this:

```
1983-05-27 02:00:00.0000 (wrong!)
1983-04-09 00:00:00.0000
1970-04-05 00:00:00.0000
1997-07-26 00:00:00.0000
1983-05-27 02:00:00.0000 (wrong!)
```

As you can see the solution is to use **CONVERT_TZ** but the second parameter may be calculated, how can I calculate the difference of the timezone for each row?

Comment: If you have a value which is effectively at 12:00 in UTC, how do you expect to tell whether the original time zone was 12 hours ahead or 12 hours behind? Fundamentally it sounds like you haven't got enough information - and it sounds like you should be using a DATE type for the result.

Comment: @JonSkeet I expect to do something like this: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME( birthday / 1000 ), CALCULATE_DIFFERENCE( birthday, '+00:00' ), '+00:00') as datetime  FROM users`,  now the question is HOW?

Comment: @JonSkeet Another way a bit more complicated is: `... CALCULATE_DIFFERENCE( EXTRACT_TIMEZONE( birthday ), '+00:00' ) ...`

Comment: I think you've missed my point. Suppose the value you've been given is the unix timestamp for 1976-06-19T12:00:00. What's the right birthday in that case? It could be 1976-06-19 (in a time zone with an offset of +12:00:00 at that point) or 1976-06-20 (in a time zone with an offset of -12:00:00 at that point). Heck, the Pacific/Kwajalein time zone has observed both of those offsets...

Comment: @JonSkeet If you can, look at here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994176/how-to-match-milliseconds-dates-with-different-timezones-in-mysql, that's the initial point of this question and is the same you are saying. I believe there's no problem with that because the timezones difference is very small (2 hours).

Comment: If you're happy for it to only work for some time zones, you should state that in the question. (You should also explain that the birthday value is the Unix time of a local midnight - that's what I've been assuming, anyway.)